# cmake - How to probably link Boost's sub_directory header files (eg: /archive/text_oarchive.hpp)?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, cmake

My use case is simple: store bunch of objects in a file. yet, I've been stuck for a week trying different stuff

I know there're many questions similar so let's start by making it clear that I've no problem compiling boost and using the filesystem.hpp header for example (CMakeLists.txt)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Project2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

find_package(Boost 1.68 COMPONENTS filesystem)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(Project2 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Project2 PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

However, I can't simply replace filesystem with the headers I need because they're not in the boost's root directory

> *text_oarchive.hpp*
>
> *text_iarchive.hpp*

this would give me the following error
`No header defined for text_oarchive; skipping header check`

To be clear, how to edit the CMakeLists.txt (mentioned above) so I can run this example (Not my actual +300 line code)

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::archive;

int main()
{
    text_oarchive oa{std::cout};
    int i = 1;
    oa << i;

}
```

> Info:
>
> OS: Linux Manjaro
>
> IDE : CLion
>
> Boost version: 1.68.0-2
>
> Boost directory: /usr/include/boost/

Comment: You need to call `include_directories(<dir>)` with `<dir>` selected so `<dir>/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp` would refer to existed file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you mean like this 'include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp)' that will compile but generate like 50 lines of undefined reference

Comment: "undefined reference" has nothing common with include directories: this error means that needed library isn't linked.

Comment: hmm ok, what should I do then? (that's my original question been stuck for a week I even made a new install and changed the system) so if you tried it and it's working mind if you share the cmakelist.txt file?

Comment: You need to link against the `serialization` library of boost not the `filesystem` lib.

Comment: thanks alot @vre really grateful finally, it's working. I never knew serialization is related to the archive headers... btw, filesystem was just an example to show that I've no problem including the library itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you need to link against the `serialization` library of boost.

Most Boost libraries are header only but a few require you to link against the corresponding library.

See [Boost header only libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) to find out whether a simple `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` is sufficient or whether you 
need to add the library to your `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ...)` call